# .NET ZIP library working inmemory

Tags: .net, zip

Is there a ZIP library for .NET working inmemory?

I need to zip and unzip files without temporary files stored on hdd. Just build archive in memory and return memory stream. Then receive memory stream and without storing zip archive on hdd unzip file and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DotNetZip Library](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/) supports working In-Memory.
Here are some [Examples](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/tree/master/Examples/c%23)

Answer (score 1):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) should work fine writing to a `MemoryStream` as far as I'm aware. To be honest, I'd be quite surprised to see *any* zip library which required you to write to a physical file. There may well be *convenience* methods to "add a file to the archive" but all the APIs I've seen on various platforms have allowed you to add a manually-created zip file entry with custom data.

Answer (score 1):

The `WindowsBase` dll in the .NET framework has had a `ZipPackage` class since v 3.0.